# How to properly import subpackages in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have an `import` error I don't understand. I made a minimal example below, a small namespace package called `p_parent` which contains no `__init__.py` file but contains another sub-package called `c_child`

here is the full arborescence:

```
p_parent
├── c_child
│   ├── c_main.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── p_main.py
```

`c_main.py` and `p_main.py` contains almost nothing. `p_parent/c_child/__init__.py` contains only an import.

Here is the shell script which rebuilds this:

```
mkdir p_parent
mkdir p_parent/c_child
echo '#!/usr/bin/env python3\n\nc_value = 4\n' > p_parent/c_child/c_main.py
echo '#!/usr/bin/env python3\n\np_value = 4\n' > p_parent/p_main.py
echo '#!/usr/bin/env python3\n\nimport p_parent.c_child.c_main as c\n' > p_parent/c_child/__init__.py
```

When the content of the `__init__.py` file is `import p_parent.c_child.c_main as c` I get an error I don't understand when I try to import the submodule:

```
>>> import p_parent.c_child
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/C/autools/release/2019.09/scade/package/p_parent/c_child/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import p_parent.c_child.c_main as c
AttributeError: module 'p_parent' has no attribute 'c_child'
```

But, what tells me I missed something really important, is that when the content of the `__init__.py` file is only `import p_parent.c_child.c_main` everything works as expected (except I have loooong names)

```
>>> import p_parent.c_child
>>> p_parent.c_child.c_main
<module 'p_parent.c_child.c_main' from '/<snip>/p_parent/c_child/c_main.py'>
>>> p_parent.c_child.c_main.c_value
4
```

with `from p_parent.c_child.c_main *` it work somehow, but I would prefere to avoid it:

```
>>> import p_parent.c_child
>>> p_parent.c_child.c_value
4
```

What is the logic here ? Why the error is so unintuitive ?

python3.6 is used

Comment: Could you supply your Python version? I think in 3.6 or 3.7 the `__init__.py` usage changed with subpackages.